# Get distance between two location using google api

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code :

```
$output = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:39.519894,-5.105667%20to:51.129079,1.306925");

$distance = json_decode($output);
```

I get the JSON response from Google API, but when I used `json_decode()` for decoding the JSON I get a `NULL` value means the function is not able to decode it.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned value has Malformed UTF-8 characters possibly because of incorrectly encoding. All you need is `utf8_encode`

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:39.519894,-5.105667%20to:51.129079,1.306925');
$data = json_decode(utf8_encode($json),true);
var_dump($data);
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EOuovR)

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you, you can pass the addresses or just latitude/longitude into $from & $to

```
$from = "Więckowskiego 72, Łódź";
$to = "Gazowa 1, Łódź";

$from = urlencode($from);
$to = urlencode($to);

$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);

$time = 0;
$distance = 0;

foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
    $time += $road->duration->value;
    $distance += $road->distance->value;
}

echo "To: ".$data->destination_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "From: ".$data->origin_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "Time: ".$time." seconds";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Distance: ".$distance." meters";
```